# Framer-Motion AnimatePresence Choppy Animation

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

I want to use framer-motion to create a transition where `element 2` slides in from the bottom as `element 1` slides out to the top when I click next.

I'm using `AnimatePresence` component to achieve this, but the result is a strangely choppy transition where `Element 2` appears in the final position briefly before it starts animating from the bottom.

[image]

**Code:**

```
<AnimatePresence exitBeforeEnter>
{    
    active === 0 ? (
        <motion.div
            key='id_1'
            initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
            animate={{ opacity: 1, backgroundColor: 'green' }}
            exit={{ y: '-100%' }}
            transition={{ duration: 2 }}>
            Element 1
        </motion.div>
    )
    : (
        <motion.div
            key='id_2'
            initial={{ y: '100%' }}
            animate={{ y: 0 }}
            transition={{ duration: 2 }}
            style={{
                backgroundColor: 'purple'
            }}>
            Element 2
        </motion.div>
    )
}
</AnimatePresence>
```

Why does the second element appear briefly at first completely ignoring the `initial` state?